# Extracting decision split values from tree graph

Tags: matlab, treeview, matlab-figure, random-forest

I am using treebagger for classification and plotted the tree graph. However, how do i extract/save values (766,4.35,2.11) from each node in the graph? Attached is the plot and below is my code:

```
Mdl= fitctree(Xtrain,Ytrain,'MaxNumSplits',4,'CrossVal','on');
        view(Mdl.Trained{1},'Mode','graph')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property that you're looking for is `CutPoint`.

```
>> Mdl.Trained{1}.CutPoint
ans =
  766.0000
    4.3500
    2.1180
```